# Find the required probability

Tags: probability

A bag has 5 identical red balls and 95 identical green balls.3 balls are drawn at random,  Find the probability such that 2 are red and 1 is green.

My approach - i understand that the chance of a ball to be drawn is independent of its colour or whether they are identical or not, rather it depends on total no. of balls available. So total outcomes should be 100C3. Now favourable should be (according to me) as 5C2×95C1×3 multiplied by 3 as order should matter(according to me as RRG RGR GRR) but in answer they havent multiplied by 3. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: You didn't multiply the denominator by $3$ too.  If you count RRG, RGR, and GRR separately in the numerator, you should count them separately in the denominator, too.  But as it is, they are counted only once in the denominator.  (The usual approach, however, is to ignore order and not multiply by $3$ in either case.)

Comment: Should be 5C2 as well, not 5C3.

Comment: oh so you mean that when i selected 100C3 i just selected them and did not think about the possible arrangements of those 3 slots. So there is no need to think about the arrangements in these kind of questions?

Comment: @KimJongUn typo

Comment: I think @BrianTung's point is that you CAN think about ordering but you have to be consistent: take into account of ordering for both numerator and denominator or do it for neither.

Comment: @KimJongUn got you, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hypergeometric Distribution:**  Let $X$ be the number of red balls obtained when three balls are drawn from this urn. Then 
$$P(X = 2) = \frac{{5 \choose 2}{95 \choose 1}}{{100 \choose 3}}.$$

This method ignores order in numerator and denominator.

From R statistical software, here is the distribution table of $X$ (first
exact to seven significant digits, then rounded to four places for easier reading):

```
x = 0:3;  pdf = dhyper(x, 5, 95, 3)
cbind(x, pdf)
     x          pdf
##   0 8.559988e-01
##   1 1.380643e-01
##   2 5.875077e-03
##   3 6.184292e-05

cbind(x, round(pdf,4))
     x       
##   0 0.8560
##   1 0.1381
##   2 0.0059
##   3 0.0001
```